# Webkit vs Processing for Interactive Applications

Tags: webkit, processing

I know this sounds a little bizarre, but there is a very simple application I want to write, a sort of unique image viewer, which requires some interactivity with the host system at the user level.  Simplicity when developing is a must as this is a very small side project.  The project does require some amount of graphical work and quite a bit of mouse based interactivity (as well as some keyboard shortcuts), but quite frankly, I don't want to dig my hands into OGL for something this small.  I looked at the available options, and I think I've narrowed it down to two main choices: Webkit (through either QtWebkit or WebkitGtk), and the language Processing.

Since I haven't actually used Processing but I do have some amount of HTML5 canvas and Javascript experience, I am somewhat tempted to using a Webkit based solution.  There are however, several concerns I have.

- How is Webkit's support for canvas, specifically for more graphically intensive processes?
- I've heard that bridging is handled better in QtWebkit than WebkitGtk.  Is this still true?
- To what degree can bridging actually do?  Can a Webkit based application do everything that an application which interacts with the files on the system needs?

Looking at Processing, there are similarly, a couple things I'm wondering.

- Processing is known for its graphical capabilities, but how capable is it for writing a general everyday desktop application?
- There are many sources that link Processing to Java, both in lineage as well as in distributing applications over the web (ie: JApplets).  Is the "Application Export" similarly closely integrated with Java?

As for directly comparing the two, the main concern I do have is the overhead of each.  I want the application to start up as snappy as possible, and I know that Java has a bit of an overhead regarding start up because it first has to start up the interpreter.  How do Processing and QtWebkit/WebkitGtk compare for start up?

Note that I am targeting the Linux platform only.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give a specific answer, because you're actually asking a few different kind of questions - and some of them you could be more precise.

Processing is a subset or child of java - it's really "just" a java framework with an free ide that hides the messy setup work of building an applet, so that a user can dive in and write something quickly without getting bogged down in widgets and ui, etc. So processing can exist by itself and the end user needs to know nothing of Java (except syntax - processing is java, so the user must learn java syntax).

But a programmer who already knows java can exploit the fun quick nature of processing and then leverage their normal java experience for whatever else is needed - everything of java is in processing, just a maybe slightly hidden (but only at first) It's also possible to import the processing.jars into an existing java program and use them there. See http://processing.org/learning/eclipse/ form more information.

"*how capable is it for writing a general everyday desktop application?*" - Not particularly on it's own (it's not made to be), but some things are possible and easy (i.e. file saving & loading, non-standard gui, etc.), and in some ways it's similar to old school actionscript or lingo.  There is a library called [controlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) that makes gui stuff a bit easier.

---

Webkit is another kettle of fish, especially if you aren't making a web-based thing (it sounds like you're thinking on using the webkit libraries as part of a larger program.  I'll admit I don't have the dev expertise with those specific libraries to give you the answer you really want, but I'm pretty certain that unless you have programming experience beyond html5/javascript you'll probably get going much faster with processing.

Good luck with whichever path you choose!

Comment: Thanks.  That explanation of Processing was really helpful.  I have several years of Java experience, and I gave Processing a bit of a 'test-drive' so to speak, and found it to be very familiar.  I agree with what you said regarding Webkit, it is much harder to get off the ground with, and if I want to do anything more complex, I'll have to get my hands dirty with some server side programming and somehow package it with my program (I am most familiar with Rails, I'll have to package that) which is completely unnecessary especially considering the scale of my project.  I think Processing it is.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful - I hate to ask, but would you mind marking the question as answered?  =)